# Check multiple Checkboxes based on the value from database using classic asp

Tags: checkbox, asp-classic

I have 3 check-boxes in my form and it allows multiple selection. My database has more than one value for that particular column and those data must be retrieved and have my check-boxes checked. For a single value i got the output. This must be achieved using classic asp.

```
<input id="_mover" type="checkbox" name="company_type" value="Mover"  <%if rs("COMPANY_TYPE")="Mover" then%> checked="true" <%End If%>>
<label for="mover">Mover</label>
<input id="_lender" type="checkbox" name="company_type" value="Lender" <%if rs("COMPANY_TYPE")="Lender" then%> checked="true" <%End If%>>
<label for="lender">Lender</label>
<input id="_childcare" type="checkbox" name="company_type" value="Childcare Center" <%if rs("COMPANY_TYPE")="Childcare Center" then%> checked="true" <%End If%>>
<label for="childcareCenter">Childcare Center</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [InStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

```
<%if InStr(rs("COMPANY_TYPE"),"Mover") <> 0 then%>
```

Comment: This is what I would do. In case the values was stored in the DB field in a particular order, or perhaps with delimiters, you could split the DB string into an array and then loop through it to get the value of each of the checkboxes.